# How can I make this complex object JSON serializable?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, serialization

I've got:

```
class Catalog():
    Categories = []

class Category():
    Subcategories = []
    Courses = []
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.Title = title
```

It goes on, where subcategories and courses have child objects as well, but I'm having trouble JSON serializing this whole complex object. It barfs:

> Object of type Catalog is not JSON serializable

I have also made all of these classes inherit from this, based on an article that I read, but it seems to have no effect.

```
class ContentBase(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)
```

How can I create an entire tree of categories, subcategories, courses, chapters, and lessons and be able to dump that all out as JSON?

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to save an object to .json?

Comment: how about using drf? You can generate very complex json objects.

Comment: To export to a file @Felipe. This reads info from a database, creates the json, and saves it to a file for consumption by the apps.

Comment: What exactly is the JSON you would like to produce?

Comment: ["Categories": [{"Title":"Category 1", "Courses": [{ ... }], "Subcategories": [{...}]]]

Comment: I've closed as a duplicate. The simplest solution is something like: `json.dumps(my_object, default=vars)`

Comment: This is assuming, of course, you are working with instance variables